# Why can I send emails to a cloud server domain from another domain on the same server from my work PC?

Tags: .net, email, networking, smtp, host

I have a Windows Service that runs on my work office PC (in the system tray) and at certain points of the day it sends emails out to a Wordpress site that is hosted on a Rackspace Virtual Server.

At the moment I am just using the basic MailMessage function and it is working e.g

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(sendfrom, sendto, subject, emailmessage);
message.IsBodyHtml = html;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

However in my config file I am using my offices mail host e.g

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="generic.smtp.myoffice"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I want to change it to use my own mailhost and mail server on my Rackspace cloud server.

If I change the network host to my own servers hostname it works AS LONG as both the send from and send to email addresses are addresses that exist on that server e.g say my Rackspace servers hostname is

myserver.monkeymagix.com

and I have two sites set up on it

www.site1.com and www.site2.com both with email accounts.

If I change the network host to

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="myserver.monkeymagix.com"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And send an email from admin@site1.com to admin@site2.com from a simple console script on my work office PC that is not connected to my Rackspace server in any way then it works and I get the email.

However if I change the recipient email address to my work email address e.g rob@office.com I get the following error when I run the script

Send Email Test
Email failed to send due to an SMTP error; Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
Send Email Test Complete

Therefore:

a) Why is the test working when the script runs on my work PC and both sender and recipient are domains on my remote Rackspace server?

b) Or inversely why does it NOT work when the recipient address (or both sender & recipient address) are my work addresses?

c) And if something weird is going on **how should I set it up** so that I can send emails through my own mail server (on my cloud server) from my work PC (or any PC) securely without just supplying the hostname of the server (no port no etc) ?

I would like to be able to move my windows service away to another machine but I need to know how to set up my application to be able to send emails through my Rackspace Cloud server properly and securely so that no-one else can send emails through it etc. My Firewall is set-up correctly and the techy boy said that he couldn't see any problems with the set-up and that people cannot just access the services/ports and mis-use it. Therefore I am wondering how come it is I can send emails from my work PC through my cloud server when there is no connection to it (that I am aware of).

Any help would be much appreciated. Both in letting me know what is going on AND how I should set up the NET class so that I can send emails through a mailhost from an EXE that maybe remote.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your cloud server has probably disabled relaying to prevent spammers from using their SMTP servers.

You probably need to enable authentication to be able to send emails to someone else via their SMTP server. However, you are most likely still limited to use the email address that you authenticate as the sender.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="name@domain.com">
            <network host="smtp.mail.com" 
                     userName="name@domain.com" 
                     password="blog.dotnetclr.com"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: (Your too quick! it keeps saving without me finishing it!) I have been told by someone that the reason I can send an email through my cloud server from/to domains ON it but NOT from/to domains NOT ON IT (e.g work) is that I must have authenticated the server with my email client e.g Thunderbird (set up passwords, port no etc). So I want to be able 2 do that BUT not with my office mailhost e.g use my own mailhost. So I should use the setttings outlined above to fix that e.g send an email from 1 domain on my cloud 2 another FROM my office PC

Comment: yes ?? no ?? - It seems you cannot hit return in this box without it saving the answer which is why you only got half answers twice.

Comment: and I did add an answer but it seems it was deleted - I don;t know if anybody but me can see it but its in a red shaded box.

Comment: @MonkeyMagix: Only power users. however, nobody really cares about deleted answers. Your answer was deleted as it's a new question and not an answer. SO is not a discussion forum.